# How strong is software licencing security based on reading the computer specs?

Tags: license-enforcement

How strong is software license security based on reading the computer specifications such as Windows installation ID, hard disk serial number, size and so forth?

**Context:**
I'm researching software licensing security strategies to implement in an enterprise product. It consists of several systems, one of which is a Qt/C++ app run as a Windows Service that captures equipment data and stores them inside a database. We want to provide our clients with the means for them to install the entire system without the need of assistance, but we want a controlled number of instances to be installed per client, so we need a license security system (and focused on the Windows service).

The system is Internet-independent, so some of our clients may want their "main" installation to be in a fully offline environment. Therefore no solution that counts with accessing outside online databases are acceptable. Moreoever, no "Pentagon level" protection is needed: we only need something strong enough to convince our non-technical customers it's better to purchase an official second copy instead of making an illicit one themselves.

With this in mind, it seems there are only two strategies that can be used: either I create a system that stops an unauthorized copy to work, or I use one which doesn't allow two copies to work simultaneously. The second strategy can be applied using dongles and similar, which I want to avoid (extra costs, 3rd party dependency, extra hardware), while the first needs some system to identify if the running app copy is legitimate or not.

It seems to me the only way to implement the first strategy is by linking a product key or similar to the single computer the proper installation is supposed to occur. And the only way of doing things without appealing to obviously weak means such as Windows Registry changes is by locking onto the PC's configurations. The problem is that I read that this approach is a weak one, that such information can easily be spoofed. I'd like to know how strong exactly this solution is. In the meantime, any suggestions of other security models without dongles are also welcomed.

Comment: Depends on how "non-technical" your customers really are.  While it may be possible to spoof hardware info, are your customers savvy enough to make it happen?  There's also a 3rd option: a licensing server that the client runs on their own network that knows all of the approved license keys.  It would still require the client devices to be networked (the inability to connect would be considered a license failure), but at least it wouldn't be reaching across the internet.

Comment: How are you going to deal with virtualization?  A very large amount of software works today via running on VMs. Also consider that copy protection is an anti-feature.  People change hardware around all the time, and you'd only be pissing off legitimate customers if you took this approach.

Comment: My question is, how do you prevent them making a copy before installation. If you give them a CD/USB/DVD/Whatever, they can just make a 1:1 copy before they install and you have no way of knowing without online connection. That is in the end why most consider DRM not worth it. (see disadvantages above)

Comment: Option 3 ... a) The majority of people are no criminals. b) You can't stop every single technical-savvy criminals. Therefore, "just don't do anything". Easier for you and less problems for paying customers.

Comment: Anyways, any HW check like you want doesn't need to have faked HW info to be circumvented. Changing your program is much easier. The same is true for any dongle requirement - I'd just remove it from the program instead of trying to make a fake dongle. (Sure, it can be made hard, but never impossible. And most likely the time would be useful for other things.).

Comment: If you really want to tie your license to something, do it via IP address.  These don't change particularly often.  When they do, have your customer contact you and ask for a new license key.  This solves the virtualization problem.  You _can_ of course get around the restriction with various different means, but at a cost of making the network config somewhat confusing.

Comment: @SteveSether How do you check IP on network not connected to the internet? Local IP changes all over the place because of DHCP and internet public IP is not a thing. Also, dynamic IPs. Also the same problem as with HW ids, how do you keep track without internet?

Comment: @SteveSether Have fun with more than half of the customers calling every day. And how this prevents multiple installs anyways? Thousands of computers with the same IP is easy, and the usual situation in big companies.

Comment: How is your activation scheme supposed to work without the internet? One circumvention to your security is to alter the program binary to not do the check... not particularly easy but an upper bound on how hard it can be. Software obfuscation might help.

Comment: @PeterHarmann You don't.  You issue a license key that's tied to an IP address.

Comment: @SteveSether So the user has to do an activation through phone or something similar even first time? That could potentially work, but IPs are not a good way to do it IMO.

Comment: @deviantfan Use static IP address, or a reserved IP.   Also, this sounds like a server, not a client.  As I'm sure you're aware, servers don't normally change IP addresses, and aren't set via DHCP.  Also, copy protection is never supposed to be perfect, just difficult enough to enforce some compliance.  In general I don't like it, and it's always too easily defeated.  It likely provides some level of protection to un-sophisticated users however.

Comment: @SteveSether Of course, with public internet servers the situation would be different.

Comment: @SteveSether It was expressly stated the computers may not be online. It sounds to me like some factory or otherwise specialized software, not servers. Computers running production in factories are often not networked at all. That is also why he is not concerned by more sophisticated attackers. They rarely focus on industry SW. PS: Than again, it may not be. Still, the "fully offline environment" was specified in the question.

Comment: @PeterHarmann indeed the product is not to be used in servers, even though it operates as such (has database, runs in Windows Server, etc.). I hope terminology is not complicating comprehension here! Factories and companies in general are this product's consumers, not home users. The server running the system may have Internet connection or not, so solution must be offline. Traditional hackers are not the concearn, but a IT worker who may want to copy the system to his next job or a different place of the same company.

Comment: @Momergil as mentioned above, the best solution(imo) is a local license server that runs fully inside the client's network. IBM SPSS(an analytics tool) uses this model, and it works very well when the internal systems do not have external network access.

Comment: @Momergil As for what characteristics to consider 'genuine', with most corporate customers you don't usually have to worry about them pirating, so any UUID should work. The Windows System ID is a decent choice. For Unix, you could use the UUID of the root fs?